Strange Plotly Heatmap behaviour
I have a web app made using Plotly/Dash. In it, I have a Heatmap which is a subplot of a scatter plot.
The heatmap has an x-axis of chemical shift (number), y-axis of time (datetime), and an intensity of a colour (number). The plot works fine for datasets with not too many increments per hour, but the minute this increases, I get issues. Even when I downsample data.
I get missing data on the plot, and then some of the data is stretched over long periods of time; it just looks weird.
I also have the code running on a different machine where I can plot data that I cannot plot on my main machine, even though my main machine has higher computing power, but even the other one doesn't work for some data.
I tried to change to go.heatmapgl, which uses hardware acceleration to make a heatmap, but here I do get a plot, but white lines in between each plot value!
I would like to figure out the root cause and fix it because this is very essential to my workflow, and I just found this issue while working on some data for a publication that is due ASAP.
My code: https://github.com/fionnf/AkkuSpin
Heatmap of desired style: https://photos.app.goo.gl/erVA427sRsz2gwT46
Heatmap when having issues: https://photos.app.goo.gl/XEPfQ7tV5kaJjKhh7
Heatmapgl with lines: https://photos.app.goo.gl/HpWm29HeJkoAK99F8
I tried downsampling; no help.
I tried something; it did not work.
Try interpolation: Doesn't work.

I have tried the code with samller numbers of spectra from the same dataset and then it works. So something todo with the volume of files, not nessecarily the frequency

Are you on the same versions of python / plotly / dash / ... ?
